# Swift Extensions from Objective-C Protocol

Tags: objective-c, swift, delegates, protocols

So I am using an Objective-C library that makes use of `MKMapView`.
So there is a class:

```
 @interface BSWeatherMapView : MKMapView
    /** The receiver’s delegate. */
    @property (nonatomic, weak) id<BSWeatherMapViewDelegate> delegate;
```

Its protocol is defined with this method:

```
    @protocol BSWeatherMapViewDelegate<MKMapViewDelegate>
    @optional 
    - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(BSWeatherMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation >)annotation;
```

My swift class has an extension doing the following:

```
extension ViewController : BSWeatherMapViewDelegate {
func mapView(mapView: BSWeatherMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: AnyObject) -> MKAnnotationView! {}
}
```

When I do this I get the following error:
Objective-C method `mapView:viewForAnnotation:` provided by method `mapView(_:viewForAnnotation:)` conflicts with optional requirement method `mapView(_:viewForAnnotation:)` in protocol `MKMapViewDelegate`

I have no clue how to get past this... anyone?

Thanks,

Comment: Unfortunately this is legal in Objective C. Is there a way around this? Our original app was in Objective-C and this all worked fine.

Comment: So is there a way for me to tell it this is the one I am trying to handle and the other once can be ignored?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that this Objective-C declaration is illegal:

```
@protocol BSWeatherMapViewDelegate<MKMapViewDelegate>
@optional 
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(BSWeatherMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation >)annotation;
@end
```

The illegality is that MKMapViewDelegate already declares a method called `mapView:viewForAnnotation:`, but with a different first parameter type. There is no overloading in Objective-C, so it is impossible to distinguish between the MKMapViewDelegate `mapView:viewForAnnotation:` and the BSWeatherMapViewDelegate `mapView:viewForAnnotation:`. If the same app were to try to implement both, the runtime would have no way of knowing which is which.

The Objective-C compiler doesn't actually stop you as long as you don't try to implement both methods; it *warns* but it does not *error*. (You, while writing your app in Objective-C, have presumably been blithely ignoring the warning; but that was a mistake, as it would have clued you in to the fact that you were already in trouble.) If you *had* tried to implement both, you would have gotten a "duplicate declaration" compile error.

But the Swift compiler, which *can* tell the difference between them because it *does* permit overloading, is more proactive and stops you from implementing *either* of them. Thus, you can *never* implement either of them on the Swift side.

Your choices, therefore, are:

- Abandon use of this library, as it is faulty.
- Fix the library to be legal (assuming you have access to the source). For example, change the name of the BSWeatherMapViewDelegate method wherever it occurs.
- Implement these delegate methods only in Objective-C, not in Swift.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I could not alter the library nor could I move to a differnent one for the time being. What I ended up doing was I created an Objective-C class that was the delegate for BSWeatherMapViewDelegate. I then created similar methods that each of the delegate methods called. Finally, in swift, I subclassed this intermediate Obj-C class and overrode the intermediate methods. Not an ideal solution but it got the job done. Thank you for all of your suggestions.

Comment: Quite clever, actually.